# Video call to iPhone (FaceTime) via Windows, Android, or web

Tags: gratis, video-conferencing

I want to perform a video call to someone with an iPhone.  The recipient of the call has no technical skills or knowledge.  They have used FaceTime on their device.

I want to make the call from a Windows or Android device, or via the web.

Is there any [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) or [android](/questions/tagged/android) software that will allow me to place a video call to an iPhone that is using FaceTime?  A web app is also acceptable.

If your answer is for Android, it must be compatible with Android KitKat.  If it is for Windows, it must be compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: Installing Skype or Hangouts from the Apple App Store is too complicated for said individual?

Comment: @Fiksdal Yes, that is correct.

Comment: There is no way to use FaceTime from any non-Apple OS. You could install OS X on Virtual Box in Windows 7, but it's a pain. The easiest thing is to help said individual install Skype. You could guide them step by step. And then teach them how to use it. If they can use Face Time, they can also learn to use Skype.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [apprtc](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) for video calling to a person with no technical knowledge or with techincal knowledge. It doesn't require any software installation. It just requires having a webbrowser on you iPhone. You can go to the link and it will prompt you to create a room or join the random room no generated when you open the website. You can pass that link to other person and that person can join you on the video call. It is free, opensource. Works in any Platform Windows, Android, Linux.

Comment: Thanks.  You mention "passing that link".  That will be too complicated for the other person, but it looks like perhaps they can just enter the room name.  Will that work?  IOW, I create the room with a unique name, and they just go to that site and enter the same name.

Comment: Yes, you can enter the unique room name and the other person enters the website, gives the same room name, will be able to join video call with you. It has support for multiple users also.. :) You can ask the other person to bookmark the URL.

Comment: Great!  Thanks Barath!  That could work!

Answer (score 0):

If the user has Facebook, then the Facebook Messenger app (available on iPhone and Android) allows for video chatting.  In addition, it's a plug-in for Facebook so it allows messaging/texting with other Facebook users.